# How to convert or copy database Firebird to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, firebird, database-migration

I have a firebird database with a `.FDB` extension and this database contains very important data. I want to see these data set in SQL Server. So I want any way to convert this database from Firebird `.FDB` to `SQL` or `.bak` file.

I tried FULL converter software and I get this error message:

[image: Error message on full converter program]

and tried DBconvert software: I also get almost the same problem:

[image]

Comment: `Unsupported on-disk structure for file...` mean:  You are accessing a higher version database file with lower version of Firebird server. See :http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq80/

Comment: Perhaps something is hidden under the error message window :)

Comment: What version of Firebird was this database originally used with, which operating system, 32 bit or 64 bit, little endian or big endian? Can you even access it locally with other tools (eg isql or flame robin)?

Comment: ODS: 32780-32768=12 : So, he tries to access ODS12 (FB3) database with either Firebird 0.x/1.x or with Interbase server

Comment: Frankly, maybe using FBExport and dumping DB into set of DBF files could be easier if it is a one time job. Unless topicstarter wants to set continuous framework for MS SQL to periodically connect into FB database and fetching some data from it.

Comment: thanks .i just using `Meastro Firebird` and i get all `dataset`

Comment: Set up a linked server to a Firebird ODBC datasource and insert the data using OpenQuery in SQL Server.